# How to get metrics of javascript/dom loading and processing time

Tags: javascript, optimization, metrics

We found ourselves working in a webpage that manages to work with >20k users in real time.

We worked so hard to optimize the back-end system but we now need to make optimizations in the front end.

The first thing I came up with was use some tool of monitoring the load time of the JS files.

But we don't really need to get the times of loading javascript, what we really need is know what parts of our javascript code are taking more time to finish.

Now we are using new relic to track our site, and know what server-side scripts need to be optimized.

But I can't see any metrics about front-end codes or witch files need to be optimized.

There's any tool out there that may help us with this?

Comment: Have your tried using Google chromes profiling tools?

Comment: yes and it's a great tool, but I also want to get statics from other users. Less powerful PC and that stuff

Comment: I would use the profilers from FF and Chrome. I really don't think it is possible to get too much data from other users. I suppose you could compare logs and find out how long it took a single user to download the requests. Batch it out on a 'X' timed basis... other than that, I don't think it is possible for you to get other user's information. Google Analytics provides a rough page load time

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test your javascript speed cross browsers is to write your own function.
wrap whatever code you want to test into a function and run that function as many times as you possibly can within 1 second counting the iterations. run that test at least five times because you will get a different result every time and then find the average number of iterations. I also suggest using chrome since it is about 4 times faster than any other browser out there when it comes to javascript performance. Test all your code and optimize it for your browser and the improvement will impact your users experience as well.

I have my own speedTest obj that I wrote which you can view at my website here http://www.deckersdesign.com/source.php which is under construction. FYI this obj finds the median of iterations not the average.

Comment: You could modify the speedtest to send the iteration count as an ajax request and save the iterations in a database to keep track of the users results